# Building a Black Net (Peer to Peer-like Network) with Participant Anonymity or Plausible Deniability

Tags: application-design, system-design

How would you programmatically design a "black net" where peer to peer-like data exchange (file transfer, chat etc) is possible but the anonymity of the seeder/sender(s) is either entirely hidden or at least all participants have 'plausible deniability', meaning their exact involvement and/or knowledge of transactions or activity on the system can't be proven beyond any reasonable doubt?

Comment: I sure hope you got this done. I really hope you got this done, need help?  :\

Answer (score 2):

There's a large number of these around ([here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_P2P#List_of_anonymous_P2P_networks_and_clients)'s a link to a list), many of them OSS. You might be able to leverage design information from some of these.